# Github Enterprise 2.2 Organization Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, github-enterprise

We have a git enterprise deployment, the URL is git.foo-partners.com. Within that enterprise github deployment, we have organizations, one of which is 'ux'.

I want to have an organization github page. From everything that I've found, I'm supposed to create a new repo, called ux.foo-partners.com? Or is it supposed to be ux.git.foo-partners.com? What is the subsequent URL that I go to? Is it ux.git.innova-partners.com? Or git.ux.innova-partners.com?

What am I not getting here :)

Comment: From https://enterprise.github.com/support: *Dedicated support for GitHub Enterprise is offered at no extra cost, 24 hours a day, 5 days a week.* Seriously, ask github for github enterprise support. Your company paid for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for support for a paying commercial product.

Comment: Yeah, there is paid Enterprise support, and GitHub does a great job with their response, however as someone who helps support an Enterprise install with thousands of users I can say with certainty that actual GHE end-users aren't always aware of the vendor support option (or many think only designated people can contact GHE support), thus, having it here on Stackoverflow.com serves a purpose in my mind. Thus, I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The DNS-related documentation around GitHub Pages doesn't really translate to Enterprise, because it isn't talking to your DNS system in the same way.

The pattern GitHub Enterprise publishes pages at is:

`https://git.foo-partners.com/pages/[organization]/[repo]`

Answer (score 0):

Ah heck, I'm sorry folks. Thanks for reminding me to check with support. I didn't even think to do that. I appreciate the bonk on the head.

Answer (score 0):

[Github Enterprise Documentation](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages)

It looks like the URI format has changed in newer versions. Just be sure to select the version of git-hub enterprise you're using from the dropdown in the documentation.